# how to catch a location history change event

Tags: javascript, next.js

clarification - I do not want to catch any router change event inside NextJS. I want to catch them outside NextJS.

I have an application written in NextJS, I have some code that is running outside the NextJS context. I want this code to catch when navigation changes happen. Links are built using NextJS link component using NextJS Router.

The code is sitting in an external JavaScript file that is loaded in _document.tsx

```
<script src="assets/scripts/testerTools.js" />
```

it loads correctly

when navigation changes I want to run a function, let's assume something simple like

```
const runfunction = () => {
  console.log("it ran");
}
```

I have tried the following

```
window.addEventListener('replaceState', () => {runfunction()});
window.addEventListener('pushState', () => {runfunction()});
window.addEventListener('popState', () => {runfunction()});
navigator.addEventListener('navigate', () => {runfunction()});
```

None of these work when I follow a NextJS link and the address bar url changes.

Is there some event listener I can attach to and run my function that will be able to listen to these changes.

I am using Firefox currently, although hopefully that wouldn't be affecting the code in this case.

Comment: `popState` is actually named `popstate`, and `pushState` is not an existing event regardless of how you capitalize it. And the `navigate` event is part of the Navigation API, which is still considered "experimental technology" - and not supported in Firefox, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigation/navigate_event#browser_compatibility

Comment: Without knowing how you actually build the link it is impossible to help. Are you using nextjs router?

Comment: thanks about the pushState clarification, it was misinformed.

Comment: updated description to describe how route changes are happening in next js.

Answer (score -1):

It seems like you're looking for a way to catch Next.js router changes outside of the Next.js framework. If you want to catch router changes that result in changes to the browser's address bar location (href) without relying on the Next.js router object, you can use the window.onpopstate event handler in JavaScript. This event is triggered when the user navigates through their browsing history, such as clicking the back or forward buttons or modifying the URL manually.

Here's how you can use window.onpopstate to catch router changes outside of Next.js:

```
// Add an event listener for popstate
window.onpopstate = (event) => {
  // The event object contains information about the popstate event
  // You can access the new URL using event.state or document.location.href
  const newURL = event.state || document.location.href;
  
  console.log('Router change detected:', newURL);

  // You can run your custom function here
  runFunction();
};

// Define your custom function
const runFunction = () => {
  console.log('Custom function ran');
  // Your custom logic here
};
```

By setting up this event listener, you can capture changes to the browser's history, including those triggered by Next.js router changes, back and forward button clicks, or manual URL modifications.

This approach allows you to handle router changes independently of Next.js's internal router and is more suitable if you want to capture all router changes happening throughout your application, not just those initiated within Next.js components.

Comment: clarifying again - I do not need to catch any router change events INSIDE NextJs, I need to catch the NEXTJS router changes outside NextJS. Since NextJS events of clicking a linke etc. results in the browser address bar having a different location href as it did before the following of the link I believe it should be possible in some way to catch that.